# Fortify -Denial of Service_Format String

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, fortify

I am seeing the Denial of Service format string fortify issue in line String.format.
Attackers are able to control the format argument to format() which could enable them to cause exceptions to be thrown or leak information.How can i fix this fortify issue??

```
 public String formatMessage(String code, Object... args) {
   Optional<ErrorDetails> error = errorRepository.findByCode(code);
   if (error.isPresent()) {
   String msg = error.get().getMessage(); //msg is for e.g "Message with parameters: %s, %s"
   return String.format(msg, args);
   }
   return "";
}
```

Comment: This error can only happen when attackers are able to write malicious messages into your error-table, so unless that is in no way possible then this may be a false-positive

Comment: Okay but is there a way to overcome this issue by making in some changes instead of marking it off as false positive.

Comment: Not using a dynamic `msg` would probably be the way to go, but I guess you can't do that

Comment: right msg will be dynamic